# How to Change Text Style and Color Inside PHP code

Tags: php, html, css

I have IPSuite 4.1.11 which have "Similar Content" Block at the Sidebar.
Im using [**Chameleon**](http://ipsfocus.net/4x/) Theme, which can be found [**here**](http://www.ipsfocus.com/themes/chameleon/)

I wanted to style it with css but i got stuck- I cant change the style of the author name. And i mean- the author name.
I successeded to style name and other text- but i want to color only the author name.

Here is the picture of the block:

[image]

Here is what i want to change:

[image]

Now here is the **Relevant** code of that author name:

```
                    {{endif}}
                    <a href="{$topic->url()->setQueryString( 'do', 'getNewComment' )}" title='{lang="view_this_topic" sprintf="$topic->title"}' class='ipsDataItem_title ipsType_break'>{wordbreak="$topic->title"}</a>
                    <br>
                    <p class='ipsType_reset ipsType_medium ipsType_blendLinks'>
                        <span>{lang="byline_nodate" htmlsprintf="$topic->author()->link()"}</span>
                        <span class='ipsType_light'>{lang="topic_started_date" htmlsprintf="\IPS\DateTime::ts( $topic->mapped('date') )->html()"}</span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </li>
        {{endforeach}}
```

Here is the **Full** "TopicFeed block" code:

```
{{if !empty( $topics ) }}
    <h3 class='ipsWidget_title ipsType_reset'>{$title}</h3>

    {{if $orientation == 'vertical'}}
        <div class='ipsPad_half ipsWidget_inner'>
            <ul class='ipsDataList ipsDataList_reducedSpacing'>
                {{foreach $topics as $topic}}
                    <li class='ipsDataItem{{if $topic->unread()}} ipsDataItem_unread{{endif}}{{if $topic->hidden()}} ipsModerated{{endif}}'>
                        <div class='ipsDataItem_icon ipsPos_top'>
                            {template="userPhoto" group="global" app="core" params="$topic->author(), 'tiny'"}
                        </div>
                        <div class='ipsDataItem_main'>
                            <div class="ipsCommentCount ipsPos_right {{if ( $topic->posts - 1 ) === 0}}ipsFaded{{endif}}" data-ipsTooltip title='{lang="replies_number" pluralize="$topic->posts - 1"}'>{expression="$topic->posts - 1"}</div>
                            {{if $topic->mapped('featured') || $topic->hidden() === -1 || $topic->hidden() === 1}}
                                <span>
                                    {{if $topic->hidden() === -1}}
                                        <span class="ipsBadge ipsBadge_icon ipsBadge_small ipsBadge_warning" data-ipsTooltip title='{$topic->hiddenBlurb()}'><i class='fa fa-eye-slash'></i></span>
                                    {{elseif $topic->hidden() === 1}}
                                        <span class="ipsBadge ipsBadge_icon ipsBadge_small ipsBadge_warning" data-ipsTooltip title='{lang="pending_approval"}'><i class='fa fa-warning'></i></span>
                                    {{endif}}
                                    {{if $topic->mapped('featured')}}
                                        <span class="ipsBadge ipsBadge_icon ipsBadge_small ipsBadge_positive" data-ipsTooltip title='{lang="featured"}'><i class='fa fa-star'></i></span>
                                    {{endif}}
                                </span>
                            {{endif}}
                            <a href="{$topic->url()->setQueryString( 'do', 'getNewComment' )}" title='{lang="view_this_topic" sprintf="$topic->title"}' class='ipsDataItem_title ipsType_break'>{wordbreak="$topic->title"}</a>
                            <br>
                            <p class='ipsType_reset ipsType_medium ipsType_blendLinks'>
                                <span>{lang="byline_nodate" htmlsprintf="$topic->author()->link()"}</span>
                                <span class='ipsType_light'>{lang="topic_started_date" htmlsprintf="\IPS\DateTime::ts( $topic->mapped('date') )->html()"}</span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                {{endforeach}}
            </ul>
        </div>
    {{else}}
        <div class='ipsWidget_inner'>
            <ul class='ipsDataList'>
                {{foreach $topics as $topic}}
                    {template="row" group="global" app="forums" location="front" params="NULL, NULL, $topic, FALSE"}
                {{endforeach}}
            </ul>
        </div>
    {{endif}}
{{endif}}
```

I inserted css term into ipsuite that says:

```
.ipstlight_auther {font-weight: bold; color:red;}
```

and changed from:

```
<span>{lang="byline_nodate" htmlsprintf="$topic->author()->link()"}</span>
```

to:

```
<span class='ipstlight_auther'>{lang="byline_nodate" htmlsprintf="$topic->author()->link()"}</span>
```

or to:

```
<span>{lang="byline_nodate" <span class='ipstlight_auther'>htmlsprintf="$topic->author()->link()"}</span></span>
```

But without success.

What do i miss?

## EDIT:

When i try to use "**spencerlarry**" first css answer i got this:

[image]

and when i add the **!important;** after each value i got that:

[image]

Why its acting like that?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your css:

```
p.ipsType_blendLinks span:nth-child(1) {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Dosent work. See details above (under edit) in the main question at the bottom.

Comment: This would probably work now. My first answer selects both `span` elements. This way only selects the first.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/aw8ycp0j/2/

I am using javascript to get the word "by" and changing it to black, that way only the authors name will be red. It is also getting the class names and iterating through to make the change, in case this is dynamically loaded content.

```
<body onload="highlight('by')">

<span class='ipstlight_auther'>by author</span>

<script>
    function highlight(text) {

    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("ipstlight_auther");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            var inputText = x[i];
        var innerHTML = inputText.innerHTML;
            var index = innerHTML.indexOf(text);

        if (index >= 0) {
        innerHTML = innerHTML.substring(0, index) + "<span class='black'>" + innerHTML.substring(index, index + text.length) + "</span>" + innerHTML.substring(index + text.length);
        inputText.innerHTML = innerHTML
      }
        }
}
</script>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.ipstlight_auther {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}

.black {
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: Its written all by php: <span>{lang="byline_nodate" htmlsprintf="$topic->author()->link()"}</span> so i dont know how to implement this

Comment: @StackBuck you said you changed the span to this `<span class='ipstlight_auther'>{lang="byline_nodate" htmlsprintf="$topic->author()->link()"}</span>` so that is what I used

Answer (score 0):

Got IT!

I changed it via ACP -> languages.

I searched in languages the term: "byline_nodate"

And changed it **from**: `By %s`

**to**: `By <span style="font-weight: bold; color:red;">%s</span>`

The result was:

[image]